# Using an AsyncTask inside a Service Class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have to upload data to a server. I am using a service that is running on the same process as my application. Should I use a Separate thread for upload process or Should I use a AsyncTask to upload data to server ?

More specifically can I use AsyncTask inside a service class ? And should I use it ? This service should always be running in memory in order to send data to the server every 5 seconds.

Comment: Why not try it yourself and find out? If it doesn't work, then come to SO for help.

Comment: Use an IntentService - onHandleIntent is already called on a worker thread.

Comment: I can't use an IntentService as IntentService terminates as it finishes its task.

Comment: Then .. don't let it finish it's task ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, the below code will run every 5 seconds. Use your regular connection code for sending part.

```
public class AsyncTaskInServiceService extends Service {

    public AsyncTaskInServiceService() {
        super("AsyncTaskInServiceService ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Connect to database here
                try {
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is **no** `onHandleIntent()` in `Service`. It should be `IntentService`.

Answer (score 5):

No problem to use AsyncTask in a service.

**NOTE / FIX :** I was wrong when I said the service runs in background, it only applis to IntentService. As noted in the comments and in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), a service does not create it's own thread :

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work.

That means you **must** use an AsyncTask (or another thread in any case) to perform your upload task.

Comment: You are wrong. A Service runs in UI thread. But IntentService runs in a worker thread.

Comment: Yup uploading data direct in Service class would freeze the UI thread. I need a separate thread for this, that's why I was thinking to do the uploading in AysncTask.

Comment: Not if the service was started in its own process. However the default run mode of a service is too run on the same thread as the ui, so in this case you are correct.

Answer (score -5):

**Use AsyncTask in a service in android**

```
package ​com.emergingandroidtech.Services;

import ​android.app.Service;

import​ android.content.Intent;

import​ android.os.IBinder;

import ​android.util.Log;

import​ android.widget.Toast;

import​ java.net.MalformedURLException;

import​ java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public​ class ​MyService ​extends​ Service​

{

​​​​@Override

​​​​public​ IBinder ​onBind(Intent​ arg0)​

{

​​​​​​​​return ​null;

​​​​}

​​​​

@Override ​

​​​public​ int ​onStartCommand(Intent ​intent,​int​ flags,​int ​startId)​

{

​​​​​​​​

//​We​ want ​this ​service ​to ​continue ​running ​until​ it ​is ​explicitly

​​​​​​​​//​stopped,​so​ return ​sticky. ​​​​​​​​

Toast.makeText(this,​“Service​Started”,​Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

​​​​​​​​try

{

​​​​​​​​​​​​new DoBackgroundTask().execute(

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​new URL(“http://www.google.com/somefiles.pdf”),

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​new URL(“http://emergingandroidtech.blogspot.in”)); ​​​​​​​​

}

catch (MalformedURLException e)

{

​​​​​​​​​​​​e.printStackTrace();

​​​​​​​​}

​​​​​​​​return ​START_STICKY; ​

​​​}

​​​​

@Override

​​​​public ​void ​onDestroy()

​{

​​​​​​​​super.onDestroy();

​​​​​​​​Toast.makeText(this,​“Service​Destroyed”,​Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ​​​

​} ​​​​

​​​​private ​int ​DownloadFile(URL​ url)

​{

​try​

{

​​​​​​​​​​​​//---simulate​ taking ​some​time ​to ​download ​a​ file--- ​​​​​​​​​​​​

Thread.sleep(5000);

​​​​​​​​}

​catch​(InterruptedException ​e)​

{

​​​​​​​​​​​​e.printStackTrace(); ​

​​​​​​​}

​​​​​​​​//---return ​an ​arbitrary ​number​ representing ​

​​​​​​//​the ​size​ of ​the ​file ​downloaded--- ​

​​​​​​​return​ 100; ​

​​​}

​​​​

private class DoBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>

{

​​​​​​​​protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls)

{

 ​​​​​​​​​​​​int count = urls.length;

​​​​​​​​​​​​long totalBytesDownloaded = 0;

​​​​​​​​​​​​for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

{

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​totalBytesDownloaded += DownloadFile(urls[i]);

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​//---calculate percentage downloaded and

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​// report its progress--- ​

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​publishProgress((int) (((i+1) / (float) count) * 100)); ​

​​​​​​​​​​​}

​​​​​​​​​​​​return totalBytesDownloaded; ​​

​​​​​​}

​​​​​​​​

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)

{

​​​​​​​​​​​​Log.d(“Downloading files”, ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​String.valueOf(progress[0]) + “% downloaded”); ​​​​​​​​​​​​

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​String.valueOf(progress[0]) + “% downloaded”, ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ​​​​​​​​

}

​​​​​​​​

protected void onPostExecute(Long result)

{

​​​​​​​​​​​​Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​“Downloaded “ + result + “ bytes”, ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ​​

​​​​​​​​​​stopSelf();

​​​​​​​​} ​

​​​}

}
```

Try this it may be work.
Thank you.