# Read web service response from Service ends with NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, networking, service

I have a class which connects to web service and reads latest data. It is:

```
public class LatestProductsReader extends Thread {
private String mResponse = "";

class SoapLatestProduct extends SoapConnector {
    public SoapLatestProduct(String web_service_address) {
        super("GetLatestParts", web_service_address);
    }
}

public void run() {
    String url = "my_web_service_address";

    try {

        SoapLatestProduct latestProduct = new SoapLatestProduct(url);
        mResponse = latestProduct.call();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String getResponse() {
    return mResponse;
}
}
```

I want this class's instance is invoked every 10 minutes from a Service. I wrote below code, but always ends with NetworkOnMainThreadException. Whats the problem?

```
public class SynchronizerService extends Service implements {
// .
// .
// .

private Timer mTimer=null; // timer handling
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),
                   0,
           TICK_INTERVAL);
       }
   };

   Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
   t.run();
   
   return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
   // cancel if service is  already existed
   if(mTimer!=null)
       mTimer.cancel();
   else
       mTimer=new Timer(); // recreate new timer
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   Toast.makeText(this, "In Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//display toast when method called
   mTimer.cancel();//cancel the timer
}


private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // display toast at every tick
                    LatestProductsReader PartCallert = new LatestProductsReader();
                    PartCallert.run();
                    PartCallert.join();
                    PartCallert.start();

                    while(PartCallert.getResponse() == null || PartCallert.getResponse().isEmpty()){
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                   }

                    String res = PartCallert.getResponse();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
               catch (Exception ex){
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in AsyncTask.

Comment: I already know the reason of the exception, but how can i fix the LatestProductReader class or the service to prevent the exception?

Comment: Changing the base class of LatestProductReader to AsyncTask didn't solve problem

Comment: You can see example of AsyncTask in Service class:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043652/using-an-asynctask-inside-a-service-class

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer for future readers. Although it can be solved in different methods, this one solved my problem. I inherited every **Reader** class from **AsyncTask** and created an observer interface for each one to inform the user class (SyncronizerService). The example classes are as below:

```
public class LatestCustomersReader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private SoapLatestCustomer reader = null;
private OnCustomerChangeListener mListener;

public interface OnCustomerChangeListener {
    void customerAdded(Customer customer);
}

public class SoapLatestCustomer extends SoapConnector {
    public SoapLatestCustomer(String web_service_address) {
        super("GetLatestCustomers", web_service_address);
    }
}

public LatestCustomersReader(OnCustomerChangeListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
    // Do my stuff
    SoapLatestCustomer reader = new SoapLatestCustomer(url);
    String response = reader.call();

    return response
}

// other AsynTask methods
}
```

And user class:

```
public class SynchronizerService extends Service implements
            LatestCustomersReader.OnCustomerChangeListener {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),
                    0,
            /*TICK_INTERVAL*/10000);
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.run();

    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void customerAdded(Customer customer) {
    // Insert to DB or whatever you want
}

private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    getProducts();   // Uses ProductReader
                    getCustomers();  // Uses LatestCustomerReader
                    // 
                    // ...
                    //
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope it can be useful.
    }
    }